# Proportional random sampling from a set of variable combinations

Tags: statistics, combinations, sampling

I have this table of variables, they can have the following values:

$v_1 \in \{1,2\}$,

$v_2 \in \{1,2,3\}$,

$v_3 \in \{1,2,3,4\}$,

I need to generate all the possible combinations $v_1v_2v_3$ of these variables. Using this example it'll be $24$ possible combinations: $111, 112, 113, 114, 212, 213, 214$, and so on. But I need to obtain a sample of these combinations, instead of being $24$ combinations I need $10$, the thing I need is to retrieve a proportional sample, not completely random results, but to give a specific weight to each variable. What would be the best way to obtain this value?

Comment: What does "aleatory" mean? It seems that English may not be your first language (if I'm mistaken about that, my apologies). If so, you may want to edit your post to include the question in your native language, and add the tag `(translation-request)` to the post. Hopefully, one of our users who is conversant in your language will see it and provide a clear translation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant random results.